# The report build with JasperReports that contains QR Code failed to run at iDempiere 2.1

Tags: jasper-reports, qr-code, zxing, idempiere

[image: Librabry addded in eclipse]I wish to show the QR Code at report generated with JasperReports. I am using Jaspersoft Studio (JSS) 6.2.0 to generate the jrxml and using iDempiere [ ADEMPIERE_MAIN_VERSION=Release 2.1,ADEMPIERE_DB_VERSION=2014-10-31].

The jrxml contains this block for showong QR code:

```
<componentElement>
    <reportElement x="53" y="10" width="99" height="29"/>
        <jr:QRCode xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
            <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$F{qrcode}]]></jr:codeExpression>
        </jr:QRCode>
</componentElement>
```

The jrxml is working fine at JSS. Now I have attached it to invoice report and while opening that report in browser from iDempiere application, it throws following error in Eclipse.

I have also added following classes in Studio.

- zxing-core from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core/3.3.1
- zxing-javase from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/javase/3.3.1

In Eclipse console I'm getting the following error:

```
Apr 21, 2022 3:43:22 PM org.apache.commons.digester.Digester error
SEVERE: Parse Error at line 1452 column 229: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jr:QRCode'. One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":component}' is expected.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1452; columnNumber: 229; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jr:QRCode'. One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":component}' is expected.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1892)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:243)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:230)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:218)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:172)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:156)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:137)
at org.adempiere.report.jasper.ReportStarter.compileReport(ReportStarter.java:1350)
at org.adempiere.report.jasper.ReportStarter.processReport(ReportStarter.java:1212)
at org.adempiere.report.jasper.ReportStarter.startProcess0(ReportStarter.java:470)
at org.adempiere.report.jasper.ReportStarter.startProcess(ReportStarter.java:345)
at org.adempiere.util.ProcessUtil.startJavaProcess(ProcessUtil.java:172)
at org.compiere.apps.AbstractProcessCtl.startProcess(AbstractProcessCtl.java:466)
at org.compiere.apps.AbstractProcessCtl.run(AbstractProcessCtl.java:272)
at org.adempiere.webui.apps.WProcessCtl.process(WProcessCtl.java:170)
```

What cause this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like iDempiere 2.1 is using the old version (5.1?) of JasperReports library. You can check the version of this library and create report in compatibility mode.

Comment: Yes, you are correct as jasper report lib should be 6.0.2 minimum to work the qr code. Using jasper studio 6.2.0 with db connecting directly its working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in oracle jdev.
when I used old version of ZXing jar files (verson 2.2 for both zxing-core and zxing-javase), then the problem has solved